# My image will not scale on :hover, as a div appears in front of it, how can I get around this?

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

Using transition and transform I am attempting to make `:hover` boxes that scale an image and slide up a caption.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2z3xea1/1/)

The caption container slide up and the image does scale BUT the image does NOT scale if the `image-details` div is rolled over, rather than the image.

How can I get around this?

The `image-details` div will always be visible on hover in front of the image; if the div was set to `100%` width and height. The image would not scale at all.

```
.grid .mosa-grid .grid-image {
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    min-height: 565px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition:all 0.5s ;
   -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ;
   -o-transition:all 0.5s ;
   -moz-transition:all 0.5s
}
.grid .mosa-grid .grid-image:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 3.2s ease-in-out;
}
.grid .mosa-grid .image-details {
    width: 100%;
    height: 360px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -360px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s, transform 0.4s;
}
.grid .mosa-grid .item:hover .image-details {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s, transform 0.4s;
    width:100%;
    height: 330px;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simplest thing to do is make sure your hover event is only for your container. That's what you're already doing for your captions when you have `.grid .mosa-grid .item:hover .image-details`.

So for your image scaling, instead of:

```
.grid .mosa-grid .grid-image:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2,1.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 3.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

Just do this:

```
.grid .mosa-grid .item:hover .grid-image {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
    -webkit-transition: all 3.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2z3xea1/4/).